# Get only the code out of Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a solution to pull out all the code of the notebook?
For example, if I wanted to generate a source file of my notebook "source.py" that contained all the code in the code cells of the notebook, is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

### nbconvert

You can use the command line tool **nbconvert** to convert the ipynb file to various other formats.
The easiest way to convert it to a .py file is:

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --no-prompt --to script notebook_name.ipynb
```

It outputs only the code and comments without the markdown, input and output prompts. There is also `--stdout` option.

- [nbconvert documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

### jq

But you can also just parse the JSON of the notebook using **jq**:

```sh
jq -j '
  .cells
  | map( select(.cell_type == "code") | .source + ["\n\n"] )
  | .[][]
  ' \
  notebook.ipynb > source.py
```

- [jq homepage](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- [Jupyter Notebook format](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/nbformat.html)

Answer (score 15):

You can do `File -> Download as -> Python (.py)` — this should export all code cells as single `.py` file

Comment: It seems to me that now this functionality is not allowed.

Comment: @V-Mor This option is only in Jupyter Classic. For Jupyter Lab (the newer replacement for Jupyter Classic), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350254/get-only-the-code-out-of-jupyter-notebook/66550565#66550565

Answer (score 7):

In case you are using **jupyter lab** then the option is:
`File > Export Notebook As > Executable Script`

Comment: Wow, that is extremely non-obvious. They should add the file extension to the option, like "Executable Script (.py)"

Comment: This is the easiest and most straightforward way!

Answer (score 3):

Since the notebook format is JSON it's relatively easy to extract just the text content of only the code cells. The task is made even easier when you use the [Python API for working with notebook files](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

The following will get you the code on standard output. You can handle it in other ways similarly easily. Bear in mind code source may not have a terminating newline.

```
from nbformat import read, NO_CONVERT

with open("Some Notebook.ipynb") as fp:
    notebook = read(fp, NO_CONVERT)
cells = notebook['cells']
code_cells = [c for c in cells if c['cell_type'] == 'code']
for cell in code_cells:
    print(cell['source'])
```

Notebook nodes are a little more flexible than dictionaries, though, and allow attribute (`.name`) access to fields as well as subscripting (`['name']`). As a typing-challenged person I find it preferable to write

```
cells = notebook.cells
code_cells = [c for c in cells if c.cell_type == 'code']

for cell in code_cells:
    print(cell.source)
```

In answering this question I became aware that the `nbformat` library has been unbundled, and can therefore be installed with `pip` without the rest of Jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

There is an "ugly" solution. Select all the cells of your notebook. Merge them, then just copy and paste all the code.

Comment: Ingenious, but not scalable to multiple notebooks.