# NO error(State changed from up to crashe)

Tags: python, heroku

2022-02-25T07:37:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mrmazores@tip.edu.ph
2022-02-25T07:38:18.384694+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user mrmazores@tip.edu.ph
2022-02-25T07:38:18.384694+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d1afaaa1 by user mrmazores@tip.edu.ph
2022-02-25T07:38:18.723319+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-25T07:38:24.743621+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python server.ipynb`
2022-02-25T07:38:25.365530+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-02-25T07:38:25.695999+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-02-25T07:38:25.753899+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-02-25T07:38:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
import json

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("densenet201v1.hdf5")

label = ('door_knock',
         'doorbell',
         'emergency_alarm ',
         'kettle_clicking',
         'kettle_running', 
         'kettle_whistling',
         'microwave_beeping' ,
         'microwave_running' ,
         'telephone',
         'wakeup_alarm',
         'washing_machine',
         'water_running')

def print_prediction (x, db):
    predicted_vector=model.predict(x)
    predicted_proba=np.argmax(predicted_vector,axis=1)
    if label[predicted_proba[0]] == label[0] or label[predicted_proba[0]] == label[1] or label[predicted_proba[0]] == label[2] or label[predicted_proba[0]] == label[9]:
        #print(db)
        return label[predicted_proba[0]]
        #print(label[predicted_proba[0]])
        #print(predicted_vector[0][predicted_proba[0]])
        #print(predicted_vector[0])
    elif predicted_vector[0][predicted_proba[0]] >= .50 and db > -30.0:
        #print(db)
        return label[predicted_proba[0]]
        #print(predicted_vector[0][predicted_proba[0]])
        #print(label[predicted_proba[0]])
        #print(predicted_vector[0])

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
    #get feature
    feature = np.array(request.json["feature"])
    dB = np.array(request.json["dB"])
    #make prediction
    prediction = print_prediction(feature, dB)
    #send in json format
    return jsonify({"prediction": prediction})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

When I open the app I get:

```
2022-02-25T16:19:38.978905+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=home--ear.herokuapp.com request_id=4fa7e23f-7e43-46ec-99f1-cc5c8644f5e7 fwd="136.158.57.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: There are at least two issues here: (a) You are trying to run `python server.ipynb` but notebooks are not executable by Python that way. What is in that file? Does it need to be a notebook? (b) Assuming you _do_ need Jupyter, it is not included in your `requirements.txt` and will therefore not be available at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I edited the question for the code. Somehow i try to debug it but not working

Comment: It is ok to change it manually to .py extension?

Comment: Additionally, i use tensorflow in my code but i didnt include tensorflow in my requirements.txt because it takes size and giving the error slugsize exceed 500 MiB

Comment: Feel free to visit my github
https://github.com/SparraWoooW/HomeEAR

Comment: "It is ok to change it manually to .py extension?"—assuming that's actually a Jupyter Notebook and not a regular Python file, no. You'll have to extract the code, e.g. see [Get only the code out of Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54350254/354577)

Comment: "i use tensorflow in my code but i didnt include tensorflow in my requirements.txt because it takes size and giving the error slugsize exceed 500 MiB"—well if you need it at runtime you'll have to declare it as a dependency. See if [Deploy python app to Heroku "Slug Size too large"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61062303/354577) helps with that.

Comment: I got new error "ImportError: cannot import name 'json' from 'itsdangerous' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/itsdangerous/__init__.py) ". But it is first time that it reads what inside my sever file. Thank you very much

Comment: I solve the new error. It runs! thank you very much!!