# Read a notebook in as plain text

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I am newer to synapse but a long time python user.  I have a synapse notebook that contains sql queries.  I document the fields in-text in that notebook in cell(s) as follows:

```
SELECT
    Field1    --| Some description of field 1
    Field2    --| Some description of field 2
    FieldN    --| Some description of field n
FROM SomeTable
```

I want to be able to read the notebook in as a plain text string into another notebook, use the **re** package in pyspark to parse the sql chunks and output the documetation as a table of fields and descriptions.  The part I can't figure out: ***How can I read in a notebook from my workspace in as string into another notbook?***

Let's say I have a notebook called MyNotebook in a directory called Gold.  In python on a local machine, I'd write something like:

```
with open('Gold/MyNotebook') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
```

But in synapse this results in an error saying:

```
File ~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:282, in _modified_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
    275 if file in {0, 1, 2}:
    276     raise ValueError(
    277         f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
    278         "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
    279         "you can use builtins' open."
    280     )
--> 282 return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Gold/MyNotebook'
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52119628/3238085   In general it is not possible to find path of Jupyter notebook. Another workflow you can do is https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237524/3238085  save the jupyter notebook to a disk location at the end of workflow. Then read from that location.

Answer (score 1):

As @user238607 said you cannot read the content of the notebook directly inside workspace.
He also given using `%notebook` exporting the notebook and parse it.
But this command not supported in azure synapse,
so what you can do is export you notebook to `.html`
and upload it in adls account.

[image]

Below is the exported and uploaded into adls account.

[image]

Now read that in synapse.

I used `fsspec` to read and parse it.

below is the code.

```
fsspec_handle = fsspec.open('abfs://data/notebook/Notebook.html', account_name="Storage_acc_name", account_key="your_acc_key", mode="r")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with fsspec_handle.open() as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'html.parser')

partial_class_name = 'jp-Cell-inputWrapper'
cell_elements = soup.find_all('div',class_='jp-InputArea-editor')

q=[]
for cell in cell_elements:
    cell_content = cell.get_text()
    q.append(cell_content.strip())

print(q)
```

Below are the queries parsed.

[image]

Now creating table.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("Field Name", StringType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("Description", StringType(), nullable=False)
])

pattern = r'\b(\w+)\s+--\|\s+(.*?)\n'

for each in q:
    matches = re.findall(pattern, each)
    field_table = pd.DataFrame(matches, columns=["Field Name", "Description"])
    spark.createDataFrame(field_table,schema=schema).show()
```

Output:

[image]